# Is there a way to concatenate two arrays in c++ and return them?

Tags: c++, python, arrays, return, concatenation

I have a recursive function in python like this

```
def recon(i,j):
    if i == 0 or j == 0:
        return []
    elif x[i-1] == y[j-1]:
        return recon(i-1,j-1) + [x[i-1]]
    elif table[i-1,j] > table[i,j-1]:
        return recon(i-1,j)
    else:
        return recon(i,j-1)
```

I am trying to rewrite this in c++, but the problem is the line

```
            return recon(i-1,j-1) + [x[i-1]]
```

I trid to do this is c++, but it dosent compile, is there any way to concatenate arrays like python and return them.

Comment: please show what you have so far in c++. For what you're trying to achieve it will probably be best to use an `std::vector` instead of an array; to a vector you can add elements, to an array, you can't (they are fixed to the size they were created with)

Comment: also this is an invalid syntax @ `[x[i-1]]`

Comment: Arrays in C++ are NOT like Lists in Python. You will need to use `std::vector` or `std::list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with arrays. But you can do this with vectors.

```
vector<int> x = ...;
vector<int> y = ...;
x.insert(x.end(), y.begin(), y.end()); // append y to x
```

You could to something similar with dynamically allocated memory, but it's easier to use vectors.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this

```
for(int j=0;j<10; j++)
    mer[j]=a[j];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++, j++)
    mer[j]=b[i];
```

where mer,a and b are already initialized array variable.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create a new array that is the correct size to contain both existing arrays and then loop through both to copy them in (not forgetting to retain an offset on the destination array when copying in the second one)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like recursion is unnecessary here:

```
vector<int> recon(int i, int j) {
    vector<int> ret;
    while(i > 0 && j > 0)
        if(x[i-1] == y[j-1])
            ret.push_back(x[--i]), --j;
        else if(table[i-1][j] > table[i][j-1])
            --i;
        else
            --j;
    std::reverse(ret.begin(), ret.end());
    return ret;
}
```

(DISCLAIMER: not tested)